# Difference in function performance between calling manually ('=') or through macros

Tags: excel, vba, performance, excel-formula

I wrote a lookup function. Its performance differs **dramatically** depending whether or not I call it by hand on worksheet itself **(through '=')** or through **macros**.

My macro does the following:

```
Function betterSearch(searchCell As Range, aCol As Range, bCol As Range)
    For Each cell In aCol
        If LCase(cell.Value) = LCase(searchCell.Value) Then
            betterSearch = bCol.Cells(cell.row, 1)
            Exit For
        End If
        betterSearch = "Not found"
    Next
End Function
```

The macro opens resultsWorkbook and dataWorkbook and then performs a search of the four values in column A from resultWorkbook in dataWorkbook and returns corresponding data from some other column of dataWorkbook.

```
'...opening resultWorkbook and dataWorkbook
For aRow = 6 To 9
    resultWorkbook.Worksheets("B3").Cells(aRow, 125).Value = _
            betterSearch(resultWorkbook.Worksheets("B3").Cells(aRow, 1) _
            , dataWorkbook.Worksheets("page 1").Range("A:A") _
            , dataWorkbook.Worksheets("page 1").Range("Z:Z"))

         resultWorkbook.Worksheets("B3").Cells(aRow, 126).Value = _
            betterSearch(resultWorkbook.Worksheets("B3").Cells(aRow, 1) _
            , dataWorkbook.Worksheets("page 1").Range("A:A") _
            , dataWorkbook.Worksheets("page 1").Range("I:I"))
Next aRow
```

It's really slow - takes **minutes** for 1 file. But when I open that file manually and type in the formula and hit Enter it calculates **instantly** (so in that regard my function **doesn't need** optimizing - it already calculates **fast** but just in the worksheet, not inside the macros).

I'm **not looking** to optimize the function. I want to *understand* **why** this difference in performance happens. I have `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` both for the main application and invisible application that runs along and does all the work:  `ExcelApp.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` and it seems to be changing the workbooks' states to manual but the slow performance is there as if the workbooks were still automatic.

Comment: Use `worksheetfunction.match`

Comment: Aside from the question - Is there a reason you need this (ahum) `BetterSearch` function in VBA? 
You basically wrote a poorly performing version of a basic Vlookup or Index/Match.

Comment: @Rik Sportel, I need it because Vlookup has a maximum number of symbols it takes in and looks for, while my funtion doesn't have that flaw. And I said in the question, betterSearch executes **fast** when I call it myself! The real problem is why it slows down in the macros.

Comment: Check the time it needs to open the workbooks only.

Comment: @UGP, It's relatively small. I have GUI that tells me when each operation starts, the look up of values consumes most of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably has something to do with using entire column ranges. 
I think when calling the function from a macro you are forcing Excel to transfer a million values to VBA for each full column reference (transferring data from Excel to VBA is very slow). 
When calling the function from the worksheet you are only transferring a range object which you then loop on cell by cell so the amount of data transferred to VBA is probably hundreds of thousands times less (depending how far down the range you have to go to find a match).

Try Setting range variables in your macro for the full column references and then passing the range variables instead of Range(I:I) to BetterSearch

Comment: Thank you. Tour answer really helped. I created `Range` variables and replaced `Range("I:I")` with `Range("I2:I1200")`. The performance improved greatly. However, it's still much slower than it would have been if I manually recakculated each value... I wonder if there is something else that could be done?

Comment: It looks rather suspicious - when I lookup only 5-10 values it goes super fast, while increasing the number of lookup values seem to increase the required time exponentially.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Find` function, and use the `MatchCase:=False` so it will be case-insensitive.

It will be much faster than looping through your Column.

**Code**

```
Function betterSearch(searchCell As Range, aCol As Range, bCol As Range) As String

    Dim FndRng  As Range

    Set FndRng = aCol.Find(what:=LCase(searchCell.Value), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, _
                            searchorder:=xlRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not FndRng Is Nothing Then ' Find was successful
        betterSearch = bCol.Cells(FndRng.Row, 1)
    Else
        betterSearch = "Not found"
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for response. But I still want to know why the results of the same function **differ**, the question was about that, not about optimizing the function.

Comment: I decided to follow your advice on optimizing my function, but, unfortunatelly, your code gives a `type mismatch` error on the `Set FndRng...` line...

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, because you loop through the cells of a range in a macro. This is terribly slow in comparison to arrays. 
Each cell.value call is slowing down. In Excel itselfe this slowdown is not so much because the Range objects are objects of the application itselfe.

It is slower to pass all needed data at once from the Application to VBA than to pass many times only little data.

If you rewrite your code litte bit it will be fast idependent from where you call it.

First store the searchValue in a variable. So you dont need to evaluate the formula for every single call. In your code the search value is evaluated for every comparison but this makes no sence because it will not change.

Second store the values of the aCol Range in an variant array. This is done once very fast for the whole column. After that you can compare every single value in the column really fast (faster than the Find or Match function [Performance comparison of Find / Match / Variant-Array](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/))

Here is your changed code

```
Function betterSearch(searchCell As Range, aCol As Range, bCol As Range)
    Dim searchVal as String
    Dim colVals() as Variant
    Dim r as Long
    searchVal = LCase(searchCell.Value)
    colVals = aCol.Value    ' Read data of whole column only once
    For r = 1 to Ubound(colVals,1)
        If LCase(colVals(r,1)) = searchVal Then
                betterSearch = bCol.Cells(r, 1)
                Exit For
        End If
        betterSearch = "Not found"
    Next 
End Function
```